# Textarea input to Array elements

Tags: php, html, arrays, forms

I wants to generate an array with different elements depending on how many words are written in the text-area. Every single word from the text-area should be in their own element in my Array. 
I have been googling this without any success and therefore want to try my luck here.

Could look something like this

```
 ----  input: "Hello I love stack overflow" -----
```

Output:

```
 Array ( [0] => Hello [1] => I [2] => love [3] => stack [4] => overflow [5])
```

Comment: You can try with explode() function http://php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php

Answer (score 1):

```
$output = explode(' ',$input);
```

then

```
print_r($output);
```

then access each by

```
$output[0],
$output[1],
```

and so on

Answer (score 0):

User explode:

```
<?php

    $pizza  = "piece1 piece2 piece3 piece4 piece5 piece6";
    $pieces = explode(" ", $pizza);
    echo $pieces[0]; // piece1
    echo $pieces[1]; // piece2
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 <?php
  $string="Welcome to CodeNair";
  // explode('separator',$string)
  $array=explode(' ',$string);
 print_r($array);
 //Output : Array ( [0] => Welcome [1] => to [2] => CodeNair )
 ?>
```

Comment: elaborate it please

Comment: PHP explode('','') method are used to break a sentence into array..              explode area two parameters    first one separator and 2nd parameter string...see examples here.. [php array to string and string to array](http://www.codenair.com/2018/02/php-array-to-string-and-string-to-array.html)